# Gnome Classic for 15.04?

Tags: gnome-classic, 15.04

"No candidate" when I try to install Gnome Classic on 15.04. Will that change? If not, what other "low-tech," lower-demanding UI options do I have for my older, weaker computer with 15.04?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An official Ubuntu based distribution is Ubuntu GNOME 15.04.

> GNOME Classic session is included. To try it, choose it from the
>   Sessions option on the login screen.

You can use the GNOME3 PPA and update GNOME3 with these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: I don't get the gnome classic session as I do get in Debian 8. Any hint?

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal an run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-flashback
```

Logout and select your preferred classic session and login back.

Comment: I'ts similar bit not exactly the same, gnome classic opens the gnome 3 dash if you press the win key so it works as both gnome 2 and gnome 3

Comment: Thanks! It worked fine. It seems this package isn't exactly gnome-classic, but it's what I've been using for the last two years thinking it was. Now that I'm at 15.04 this was exactly was I was looking for.