# Install gnome classic on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: gnome, gnome-classic, ubuntu-gnome

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 and it works fine but I want to install gnome classic fallback, do anyone know how?

Answer (score 9):

If you want GNOME Flashback (fallback), run this.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gnome-panel gnome-flashback gnome-session-flashback indicator-applet-appmenu
```

You will then have options for either GNOME Flashback (Metacity) and GNOME Flashback (Compiz) available when you logout and get back to the login screen.

Answer (score 2):

The latest version of Flashback was released last year, so it hasn't been updated in a long time.

However, according to [this Ubuntu Forums thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2291032), it should work fine. Really, the best way to see is to try it out yourself.

If you like the panels and all the fun things from GNOME 2.x, you may want to think about Ubuntu MATE. It's an updated and maintained version of GNOME 2, with an official 16.04 release.

Comment: will gnome 3 work on it, see this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/613336/gnome-classic-for-15-04

Comment: What about GOME Flashback do you like? The bottom panel?

Comment: I was thinking about a new version of gnome classic when I installed ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Flashback is dead but gnome classic is now included in gnome. easiest things is to install ubuntu gnome directly installing the desktop in unity works fine too. .

Comment: GNOME Flashback is not dead! And when GNOME has new minor (not micro) version there is also new GNOME Flashback version.