# Replace Ubuntu MATE default apps with GNOME ones

Tags: gnome, 16.04, mate, default-programs, ubuntu-mate

I recently installed Ubuntu MATE and I want to replace default MATE apps with GNOME ones like this:
Caja to Nautilus
Pluma to Gedit
MATE terminal to GNOME terminal ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there's any easy way to do this within the MATE desktop environment, since the MATE desktop and MATE apps are designed, coded, and tested to work together as a cohesive desktop.

However, there is a way to run GNOME (which includes all the latest versions of nautilus, gnome-terminal, gedit, etc) in a mode that closely resembles the MATE desktop.

First install the `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` package, or do a fresh install of Ubuntu GNOME. This will install the full GNOME desktop environment. Next, install the `gnome-flashback` package. This installs the "classic" mode of GNOME, which is similar to Ubuntu MATE. Now, at the login screen you can choose to use the "flashback mode", and you'll see a desktop that's like Ubuntu MATE, but with all the latest GNOME apps. More information here: 
[Gnome Classic for 15.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/613336/gnome-classic-for-15-04)

Comment: But MATE apps are just GNOME apps renamed to avoid conflicts with GNOME components...
http://mate-desktop.com/

Comment: That's mostly  correct. But they are forks of the original projects, so they have their own code containing modifications for MATE, and different version numbering, and their packages are not interchangeable with the original GNOME software.

Comment: So I shouldn't worry about installing software (GNOME apps) I'm used to, because they have the same functions apart from name?

Comment: Name was the reason I made this question, because I like to have same apps no matter what DE I'm using, and It's very helpful to have same configs for every OS installation (I have separate /home partition).